# How to use Google Cloud API in my own website and control it

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to develop a website to manage GCP(google cloud). and achieve use ssh from my website to manage GCP virtual machine without login dashboard.

The website I develop made user without login to GCP dashboard, instead of my website.
For example, after login my website and display the manage items.
(pleases take look attached photo)

I didn't find any clue from GCP. might ask it's any API by GCP publish can achieve on my own website? or what kind of structure can achieve it.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/okP04.jpg

Comment: One of the reasons that Google Cloud's web interface is so easy to work with is many person-years of development. Google does not provide that code for you to use. You will need to redevelop those features yourself. Since your interest is in SSH in a web browser, take a look at how third-party products and libraries do it. Then invest the time to understand how SSH operates in Google Cloud regarding key management, private/public connections, tunneling, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all Google's services' functionality is available through APIs. A good way to interact with Google's APIs is through [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer). Additionally, these APIs are **all** provided through SDKs (libraries) in multiple languages.

So, you can automate what you need.

With Google Cloud services (e.g. Compute) there are 2-3 different libraries you can use. These are explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained).

Now, if I understand your question correctly, you want to automate SSH'ing to Compute Engine VMs. Google uses SSH to do this. If you used `gcloud compute instances ssh ... --log-http` (maybe  `... --verbosity=debug`), you can see this for yourself. From Console, it uses a tool that SSH's through the browser.

Either way, you should use SSH for the secure session.

To enumerate lists of instances, you can use Compute Engine's API's [instances.list](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list).

> **NOTE** I would caution you about providing this functionality for others from your site. You will need to manage your customers' private SSH keys in order to permit them to SSH into their instances through your site. Many will correctly consider this a potential security risk and will expect some assurance that you're able to do this securely and reliably before they'll consider using your solution.

Comment: Hi, thx a lot for your suggestion. Actually, I hope to find an API with SSH from GCP.
and develop my website for management. 

Thank you so much. I think as GCP security policy looks don't provide this way to management.

Thank you.